# displaying an object in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, firebase

I ahve created a variable that gets its data from Firebase. It returns an object with the two parts to the object within it, however when I try to use string interpolation it returns `[object Object]`. I have tried doing an *ngFor however I get this error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

This is my variable:

```
this.groupMembers = this.currentGroup.members_uid;
    console.log(this.groupMembers)
```

the `console.log` returns this in the console:

```
  {7TkrG4Ty2pf2OBy9whhSsSl1sC22: true, by285gAhkdRg4rDMkujzSQXxGAJ2: true}
7TkrG4Ty2pf2OBy9whhSsSl1sC22
:
true
by285gAhkdRg4rDMkujzSQXxGAJ2
:
true
__proto__
:
Object
```

1. How do I access this to display its content in my html?
2. How do I create a new variable in my ts file that also 'loops' through them in some way so I can access each part individually?

EDIT ****

```
 this.currentGroup = this.currentGroupId$
        .pipe(switchMap(id => this._group.getGroupById(id).valueChanges()))
```

this then returns an Observable which I input to a child component like so:

```
*ngIf="currentGroup | async as group" [currentGroup]="group"
```

and call it:

```
@Input() currentGroup: any;
```

Comment: Can you show the code which gets data from Firebase?

Comment: @WazzaEl updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe AngularJs used to display the contents of an object when interpolated.  This isn't a behavior supported by default in Angular, but it is easy to implement.

The quick and dirty way would be to add a function to your component that converts an object to a string using `JSON.stringify()`.  A cleaner solution would be to create a Pipe to perform that same activity:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'stringify'
})
export class StringifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return JSON.stringify(value);
  }
}
```

One you add the Pipe you can display it in your code template quite simply.

```
<pre>{{groupMembers | stringify}}</pre>
```

You can easily extend the Pipe to format the code so the display is nicer, or you can create a component that renders it nicely as html instead of using a `pre` element.  Heck, I'm surprised a component doesn't already exist.

Comment: yeah I feel you, seems like its quite a common thing that should be easily avoided in angular? I dont know though!

Comment: Basically I pass each of the content of the object back to firebase into another collect as they are seen here, however when I pass them back it says :[object Object] : true instead of each of the two ids then : true if that makes sense? So what I understand from this is tht it would work for posting it to my html but not to that?